# Why is this Rails assert_generates giving an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4.0.0.

#### Test Case

```
test "routing balance" do
  assert_generates '/users/1/balance', { controller: 'users', action: 'balance', id: '1' }
```

#### Error

```
  1) Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_routing_balance:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"balance", :id=>"1"}
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:18:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

#### Console

```
irb(main):229:0> app.user_balance_path 1
=> "/users/1/balance"
```

#### Browser (Works)

```
http://localhost:3000/users/1/balance
```

#### Routes.rb

```
resources :users do
  get 'balance', to: :balance
```

#### Rake routes

```
 user_balance GET    /users/:user_id/balance(.:format)           users#balance
```

#### Other Test (works)

```
test "routing" do 
  assert_generates '/users/1', { controller: 'users', action: 'show', id: '1' }
```

#### Reference

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#rails-specific-assertions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using 'user_id' instead of 'id' in your test since that is what you have in your routes